# Can a hypothetical question (scenario) on the workings (mechanics) of the government be asked at this site?

Tags: discussion

I have a hypothetical question related to the workings of the electoral college that I would like to explore the answer to but I do not know if hypotheticals are okay here. What is the policy?

Answer (score 2):

A hypothetical based on the current mechanics is entirely OK.  E.g. what happens if Trump and Clinton both get 269 electoral college votes is on-topic.  The biggest problem that I've seen with hypotheticals is when they invite speculation from answers.  Speculating in a question that can have concrete, objective answers is fine.

All that said, I personally would want to see the question before making a judgment.  I don't think that a hard and fast rule like hypotheticals are always OK or never OK would really work.

Comment: Fair enough. I will need to consider if what I want to ask about will invite speculation or not. It's an edge case to be sure. It has to do with an elected (by the public vote in November) President becoming *unelectable* before the EC votes in January.

Comment: @O.M.Y. That sounds on topic to me.

Comment: See [here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/6404/4666) or [here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10264/4666) or [here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/4729/4666) for similar questions.  The greater problem is that it might be closed as a duplicate of the first question.  The answers would be rather similar.

Comment: What I always consider problematic are questions in the pattern "How would X behave in situation Y" when that is not strictly defined by the rules X is bound to. We can not predict the behavior of people.